# Loopback + Angular: `findById` Error. Expected response to contain an object but got an array

Tags: angularjs, filter, loopback

I'm trying to apply a filter for a chat room that makes it so that I only see messages that have a foreign key relationship to that chat room displayed, so I'm trying to pass `shownMessages` to the view. How do I do this effectively? The current error I'm dealing with is `Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration for action`findById`. Expected response to contain an object but got an array`. I'm searching as best as I can and still, nothing to my avail.

```
  // for inside the room
  // node - injection order is extremely important
  .controller('InsideRoomController', ['$scope', '$q', 'ChatRoom', 'ChatMessage', '$stateParams', '$state', function($scope, $q,
      ChatRoom, ChatMessage,  $stateParams, $state) {
        // we include Chatroom as a param to the controller and func since we work with that to display it's contents
        // only show messages pertaining to that room
        $scope.shownMessages = [];

        ChatMessage
          .findById({ id: $stateParams.messagesInChat })
          .$promise
          .then(function(showMessages) { // once we query to find chat rooms
            $scope.shownMessages = shownMessages;
          });

  }])
```

`relationsInChat` is the name of the foriegn key relation I made in loopback between ChatRoom and ChatMessage which was generated in `chat-room.json`:

```
{
  "name": "ChatRoom",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "city": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "ChatMessagers": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "ChatMessager",
      "foreignKey": ""
    },
    "chatMessages": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "ChatMessage",
      "foreignKey": "messagesInChat"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

**Edit: How do I get all messages belonging to the chat via foreign key? I'm trying to use stateparams but not sure how**

Comment: in find by id method, may be **id** param getting some other value instead of number, so check in console what $stateParam is returning

Comment: Okay thanks, I'm getting undefined

Comment: I'm just not sure how to get the all messages belonging to the chat via foreign key at this point.. I'm trying to use stateparams but not sure how

Comment: I may need a where clause of some sort

Answer (score 1):

Try printing `$stateParams.messagesInChat` value. 
As the error shows, it contains an array rather than object(means multiple value is present instead of single ID), but findByID accept only one value as you are finding the data for only one ID.

Comment: Thanks it ended up being undefined. I'm just not sure how to get the all messages belonging to the chat via foreign key at this point.. I'm trying to use stateparams but not sure how

Answer (score 0):

I got what I needed. Needed an include filter! http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Include-filter.html

```
  .controller('InsideRoomController', ['$scope', '$q', 'ChatRoom', 'ChatMessage', '$stateParams', '$state', function($scope, $q,
      ChatRoom, ChatMessage,  $stateParams, $state) {
        // we include Chatroom as a param to the controller and func since we work with that to display it's contents
        // only show messages pertaining to that room
        $scope.shownMessages = [];

        function getMsgs() {
          //User.find({where: {vip: true}, limit: 10}, cb);
          return (ChatRoom.find({include: ['ChatMessages']}))
        };

        $scope.shownMessages =  getMsgs();
        console.log($scope.shownMessages);
  }])
```